# ls reports a different inode for a system directory (/home) in an interactive shell and in a script

Tags: systemd, inode

If I'm working in an interactive shell of any user, an inode list query for `/home` returns:

```
[postgres@localhost ~]$ ls -ild /home
2 drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 May 20 16:20 /home
```

However, a script called in a systemd unit file by an `ExecStartPre=` clause, and specified to run as a specific user (i.e. `User=postgres`), which runs the same `ls` command shown above, displays a completely different inode and fails, stopping me from running the systemd unit normally:

```
10364 d--------- 2 root root 40 May 20 15:06 /home
```

I don't really have a clue why is this so. It is actually very strange. Can somebody explain what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The stock form of the systemd unit file I was trying to access includes the `ProtectHome=true` clause, which as per the systemd documentation:

```
ProtectHome=
       Takes a boolean argument or "read-only". If true, the directories /home, /root and /run/user are made inaccessible and
       empty for processes invoked by this unit.
```

Changing the clause to `false` made `/home` available to the script.